# Where can I expose Visualforce Pages in Salesforce Chatter?

Tags: mobile, touch, publisher, global-actions

> How can I expose a Visualforce Page in the Salesforce Chatter mobile app?

I'm aware that **Salesforce Touch** allows Visualforce Pages to exposed as Touch-enabled Tabs:

[image]

And I can get "Create Record Action" to appear with its nice slim page layout in **Salesforce Chatter**:

[image]

But I cannot for the life of me get "Custom Visualforce Actions" to display in Salesforce Chatter. Can anyone lend some light on whether this is, should be, or will be possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the page to **Available For Salesforce Mobile Apps**. This is found in *Setup > Develop > Pages > Edit (Page Name)*. First, you need to specify a page version of at least 27.0 (on the Version Settings tab), then you can check the box to make the page available. You can now also add pages to the navigation menu, under Setup > Administration > Mobile Administration > Mobile Navigation.

Comment: Thanks for lending your advice here. The question title (edited) was a TOTAL misnomer on my part, I'm looking to expose them in **Salesforce Chatter** -- I've confirmed that the `Page` used in my `Custom Action` is `Available In Touch` but to no avail :(

Comment: I just tried this, and it appears that they don't work. The documentation also says nothing about custom actions in chatter mobile, so I don't think it's possible at this time. It's really a shame, too, as we could do so much more if we had Visualforce access.

Comment: I think as of the release, the above option has been renamed to 'Available for Salesforce Mobile Apps'. There's also a new setup option Administration>Mobile Administration>Mobile Navigation to control what shows up in stage left.

credit: http://www.verticalcoder.com/2013/11/06/chatter-mobile-and-visualforce/

Comment: Correct. It's been renamed in Winter '14 specifically to invalidate my answer (just a periodic product refresh, this is just a bit of humor).

Answer (score 6):

As of the latest version of Chatter Mobile(v4.2), you can now include VF tabs in the app. Mark the VF page as Available to Mobile apps and create a tab that uses that page. Then go to Administer>Mobile Administration; you’ll find a new option called Mobile Navigation. This lets us rearrange “stage left” in the Chatter Mobile app. We can add and remove standard components and also add our mobile enabled Visualforce tabs here.

Once you are all done, fire up Chatter Mobile!

I wrote a blog post with a bit more info: http://www.verticalcoder.com/2013/11/06/chatter-mobile-and-visualforce/

After playing around with Chatter Mobile more, I've also realized you can embed mobile pages on records by editing the page layout and dragging mobile ready pages to the Mobile Cards section of the page layout.